# Symfony 2.1 FOSOAuthServerBundle webservice authentication

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to load users for OAuth authorization from a remote webservice. Webservice needs login and password to get information about user. This [article](http://blog.vandenbrand.org/2012/06/19/symfony2-authentication-provider-authenticate-against-webservice/) said, that I need to create new UserProvider. But I can't understand how to load user only by username without password:

```
// Try service
    if ($record = $this->service->getUser($username)) {
        // Set some fields
        $user = new User();
        $user->setUsername($username);
        return $user;
    }
```

I need something like a proxy auth to remote service. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get into the security component of Symfony is by reading the documentation on this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html. Work trough the examples and try to start small.

Your next step could be the implementation of a custom `AuthenticationListener`. Take a look at the classes in `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall`, this should give you a head start. Also, look for similar bundles on [Packagist](http://packagist.com/) and check out their code.

Good luck!